# Correlation with Output from Sliding Window Subsamples

Tags: variance, independence

This is a different situation from rolling average or time series smoothing.

Say I have 10 samples and four variables (x, y, S, T) associated with each sample.
The results of a function R = y/x^e, i.e. R1 - R10, are correlated with S.
In fact, e is the value of the exponent the maximizes the correlation between R and S.

After ranking my samples with respect to T, I draw six sub-samples (sliding window)
i.e. #1 - #5, #2 - #6, etc. and optimize the correlation between R and S for each subsample.

I am interested in the correlation (or regression) between e1 - e6 with medians of T for each subsample.

How do I take into account the non-independence of the subsamples when calculating the variance/covariance?